# His brother "hooked" him up with this bachelor party

Tags: meaning-in-context

I was watching the film ["Bachelor Party Las Vegas"](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0432373/) and one of the characters utters the phrase:

> His brother **hooked** him up with this bachelor party

(emphasis mine)

When I looked up *hooked* in the Oxford English Dictionary I found

> 1. Curved like a hook
> 2. Addicted

This does not really make sense in the context of the film. What is the meaning of *hooked* here?

Comment: @drm65 Thanks for restructuring my question!

Comment: Actually, Matt Ellen seems to have done most of it.  I only formatted a couple things in there.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not so much *hooked* as an adjective, but *hooked up* as an idiom and verb.

Hook can be used as a verb that means (from my OED):

> **Hook** *verb* - grasp or catch with a hook; fasten with a hook or hooks.

When you hook things, for example

> I hooked my TV to my XBox.

you are joining them together by some means. This can equally be expressed as

> I hooked up my TV to my XBox.

When it comes to one person hooking up another with something, as in your example, the joining together is a euphemism for giving something to someone. So the example can be read as

> His brother threw him this bachelor party.

Also, another example would be

> My man Dexter here **hooked me up** with this sweet ride.

Indicating that Dexter gave the speaker a nice car.

*Hooked up* can also have racier connotations, which I don't think are present in your example.

E.g.

> I hooked up with Clarice again, last night. Man, she goes like a train!

Where *hooked up* implies sexual intercourse. Here, I think, the analogy to joining is obvious.

Comment: His brother met him can't be correct. Because this is a phrase from a movie I was watching "Bachlor Party Las Vegas", may be "his brother aroused interest in him to "join" the bachelor party"

Comment: @poorenglish, I have updated my answer

Comment: Great answer. Basically, "hooking up with <person>" means having sex with them, whereas "hooking up <person> (with <something>)" means giving them some sort of good deal or opportunity. My boss still hasn't got the memo on this and uses "let's hook up" the way you'd say "let's touch base" or "let's meet again"- gets a little awkward in client meetings

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, the key here is to know that **hooked up** means `attach`. So the bachelor party was `attached` to his life by way of his brother.